# Paste Graph generated through Macro at the desire location

Tags: vba, excel

I am generating graph using macro in the location. However, since I am generating multiple graphs, they are stacked over each other. I have not been able to position them properly next to each other. How do I do it? Below is my code:

```
Range("A318:A322,B318:B322").Select
'In the active sheet we add a chart
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
' We set the source data for the chart
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
    "'Assessment'!$A$318:$A$322,'Assessment'!$B$318:$B$322")
 'We define the type of chart
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
' Before we can perform an action on the chart we need to activate it
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Activate
'We perform the cut operation
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Cut
'we select the Sheet2 where we wish to paste our chart
'Sheets("Sheet2").Select
'We now paste the chart in the Sheet2 whic has become the active sheet after selection
'ActiveSheet.Paste
'we return to sheet1
Sheets("User Report").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste 
' we select the cell F9 in sheet1
Range("D1").Activate
```

How do I now paste the chart in the desired cell of my choice in the sheet?

Comment: You can try to activate a `Range` first in the destination sheet before pasting.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you put the word "we" in the front of all the comments?  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No selecting or activating required:

```
Dim co

Set co = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart()
co.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Assessment'!$A$318:$A$322,'Assessment'!$B$318:$B$322")
co.Chart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
co.Cut

With Sheets("Sheet2")
    .Paste
    Set co = .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)
    co.Left = .Range("D1").Left
    co.Top = .Range("D1").Top
End With
```

Alternatively, put the chart in the right place on the right sheet to begin with.

```
Dim co As ChartObject

Set co = Worksheets("Sheet2").Shapes.AddChart(Left:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D2").Left, _
            Top:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D2").Top)
co.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Assessment'!$A$318:$A$322,'Assessment'!$B$318:$B$322")
co.Chart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
```